# Make all properties of object mutable

Tags: javascript, oop

How do i define properties of an object, so if one of them is changed all other are automatically updated.

I have come up with this code so far, but it doesn't work:

```
function CreateNamed(first, last) {
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
           "firstName": {
            value: first,
            writable: true
        },
            "lastName": {
            value: last,
            writable: true
        },
            "fullName": {
            value: first + ' ' + last,
            writable: true
        }
    });
}
```

So after a new object is created it can be changed appropriately:

```
var b = new CreateNamed('Bill', 'Gates'); // Bill Gates
b.firstName = 'Paul'; // b.fullName = Paul Gates
b.lastName = 'Wood'; // b.fullname = Paul Wood
b.fullName = 'Chuck Norris' // b.firstName = Chuck, b.lastName = Norris
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`value` is not computed dynamically. It won't change as the object changes. In order to dynamically compute properties, you need to define getters and setters using [`get` and `set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties):

> **get**
>   A function which serves as a getter for the property, or undefined if there is no getter. The function return will be used as
>   the value of property. Defaults to undefined.
>
> **set**
>   A function which serves as a setter for the property, or undefined if there is no setter. The function will receive as only
>   argument the new value being assigned to the property. Defaults to
>   undefined.

```js
function CreateNamed(first, last) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
           "firstName": {
           get: function() { return this.first; },
           set: function(name) { this.first = name; }
        },
            "lastName": {
           get: function() { return this.last; },
           set: function(name) { this.last = name; }
        },
            "fullName": {
            get: function () { return this.first + ' ' + this.last },
            set: function (name) {
              if (!name.match(/^[a-z]+ [a-z]+$/))
                throw new Error('I cannot parse that name')
              var parts = name.split(' ')
              this.first = parts[0];
              this.last = parts[1];
            }
        }
    });

}

var user = new CreateNamed('bob', 'smith');
document.write(user.fullName); // bob smith

user.firstName = "john"; 
document.write(user.fullName); // john smith

user.fullName = "tony brian";
document.write(user.firstName); // tony
document.write(user.lastName); // brian
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks a ton. I was thinking that writing `writable:true` will be enough to make the the properties updatable.

Comment: You forgot to declare `parts` in the fullName setter.

Comment: One more thing: if I want to accept the input to `fullName` only in the format firstName + space+ lastName, do I set the condition in the `get` function of `'fullName'`?

Comment: @Clarity No. Raise an exception in the `set` for `fullName` if the input does not conform to your requirements. See my update. Please don't use that regex for validating names in the real world...

Answer (score 0):

[@meagar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29049786/1529630) is correct.

But there is a simpler approach: just assign the `firstName` and `lastName` properties as usual, and then only define a getter and setter for `fullName`:

```js
function CreateNamed(first, last) {
  this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
  Object.defineProperty(this, "fullName", {
    get: function () { return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName },
    set: function (name) {
      name = name.split(' ');
      if(name.length != 2) throw new Error('I cannot parse that name');
      this.firstName = name[0];
      this.lastName = name[1];
    }
  });
}
```

```js
function CreateNamed(first, last) {
  this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
  Object.defineProperty(this, "fullName", {
    get: function () { return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName },
    set: function (name) {
      name = name.split(' ');
      if(name.length != 2) throw new Error('I cannot parse that name');
      this.firstName = name[0];
      this.lastName = name[1];
    }
  });
}

var ouput = [];

var user = new CreateNamed('bob', 'smith');
ouput.push(user.fullName); // bob smith

user.firstName = "john"; 
ouput.push(user.fullName); // john smith

user.fullName = "tony brian";
ouput.push(user.firstName); // tony
ouput.push(user.lastName); // brian

document.body.innerHTML = ouput.join('<br />');
```